# Are Transition animations supposed to be 'Janky' the first time they are run in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to navigate between pages, and have made a few transitions for them. They work fine, but not on app bootup. They are really jittery. I don't know if this is time based, or the first few tries, but they work as they should afterwards. I am just building the skeleton right now, so I am a bit worried.
I have tried this on both emulator, and a real device, yet same problem.

`Transition Code`

```
class Fade extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget child;

    Fade({required this.child}) :
    super(
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      pageBuilder: (context,animation,secondaryAnimation) => child
    );

    @override
    Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) => 
    FadeTransition(
      opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1).animate(animation), 
      child: child);
}
```

`Call`

```
onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                Fade(child: const Register()));
                },
```

I have tried using dedicated packages, or none at all. Same thing, I have read on the Shader Compilation Jank, but I need a more appropriate solution. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you run it in debug or release mode? more: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes

Comment: @pskink I have been running in debug, I will give the other modes a try and report back.

Comment: @pskink So, it works on 'flutter run --release.' Should I forget about this problem then? As it will be good when I wrap it up.

Comment: check it out: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes#debug - it explains what you can expect in this mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In debug mode, compilation is optimized for fast development and run cycles, but not for execution speed, binary size, or deployment. This is why application performance, including transitions, can be janky.

See: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes#debug

---

**Another thing might be worth knowing:**

In debug mode, by default you see a debug banner on the top-right of the screen. The reason for the existence of this banner is explained in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/debugShowCheckedModeBanner.html):

> This banner is intended to deter people from complaining that your app is slow when it's in debug mode. In debug mode, Flutter enables a large number of expensive diagnostics to aid in development, and so performance in debug mode is not representative of what will happen in release mode.